# Replacing $R_3$ with $2R_1 - 3R_3$ is changing the matrix's determinant. Why isn't the determinant the same from summing multiples of rows?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am trying to solve the determinant

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
        3 & 10  & 1 \\
        0 & 3 & -3 \\
        2 & 2 & 5 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

My plan was to add another 0 below the existing 0 in the matrix, so I can get a nice co-factor expansion down the first column.

So, I replaced the $R_3$ with $2R_1 - 3R_3$:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
        3 & 10  & 1 \\
        0 & 3 & -3 \\
        0 & 14 & -13 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

However, the determinant has been changed. The determinant above is -3 while the one below is 9.

May I ask if my understanding of the rule of replacing a row with the sum of scalar multiples of other rows flawed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant is unchanged by adding a multiple of a row to a given row, so for example,
$$
R_3 + 2R_1 \to R_3 
$$
(or $R_i + t R_j \to R_i$ for any row indices $i, j$ , any scalar $t$) doesn’t change the determinant.

However, the determinant scales by scaling a given row, so for example
$$
R_3 \to -3R_3 
$$
changes the determinant by a factor of $-3$
(or $R_i \to sR_i$ for any row index $i$, any scalar $s$ changes the determinant by a factor of $s$).

Your modification of the matrix is the composition of both, so the determinant is scaled by $1 \cdot (-3) = -3$, agreeing with your two determinant calculations.

Comment: Thank you so much. You went over my mistake, and even went further to tell me the additional operations that the determinant should have gone through. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

*If we add a scalar multiple of one row to another row*, the determinant does not change.

Note that this is less general than *replacing a row by a sum of multiples of other rows*.